# Android Eclipse AVD window won't close

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-11.04

I'm running Eclipse on an Ubuntu host with the Android SDK plugins.  I cannot seem to close the AVD window gracefully.  I've tried actually powering down Android and it gets stuck in the endless "Power off shutting down" screen.  I end up having to start killing processes which the Eclipse IDE doesn't particularly like.

It this a known issue with Eclipse/Android SDK/Ubuntu?  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: kill the processus of eclipse : kill -9 PIDOFECLIPSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, "Power off - shutting down" stays on the screen forever.

As far as I understand it, you don't have to shutdown the emulator at all. The first time you start it choose to "Save to snapshot". Once it's started close it down (simply close the window) and it will persist its state to the snapshot (it takes a few seconds). This will be your starting point for the future runs.

After that choose "Launch from snapshot" option (and clear the "Save to snapshot" option) when starting the emulator and it will continue from where you left it last time. Again you will close it simply by closing the window and since you clear the "Save" option you'll always resume from the same state.

If you need to do a 'cold boot', just tick "Wipe user data" and it will start from scratch.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but I'm not sure if this has been pointed out yet;

If you right-click on the AVD Manager's title bar, you can select "Close" (keyboard Alt+F4). This closes only the AVD Manager and leaves the emulator untouched.